# cinnamon resize window to default size by hotkey

Tags: linux, linux-mint, cinnamon

I'm using mint 18.1 and searching a way to resize of opened window and center it by hotkey (resize to default value that set up).

In cinnamon keyboard preferences I found in shortcuts a way to set window's position at center, but didn't find anything about set default window size (in other preferences sections).

Is there a way to do such stuff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install [Devilspie](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Devilspie):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install devilspie
```

> Devilspie is a non-gui utility that lets you make applications start in
> specified workplaces, in specified sizes and placements, minimized or
> maximized and much more based on simple config files.

Create a Devilspie configuration directory for the current user and then create a configuration file for devilspie, for example for gnome-terminal:

```
mkdir ~/.devilspie && echo gedit ~/.devilspie/gnome-terminal.ds
```

Add a desired contents, for example:

```
(if (is (application_name) "Terminal")
     (begin
         (geometry "800x400")
         (center)
     )
)
```

Then assign a custom keyboard shortcut in Cinnamon:

Go to main menu and search for app "Keyboard" and run it.
Choose the "Shortcuts" tab, choose Category "Custom Shortcuts" in the left and click "Add custom shortcut"
[image]

In the command window, enter "devilspie"

[image]

Click Add an in the Keyboard bindings, choose your desired shortcut, for example I chose Ctrl+Alt+D and close this window:
[image]

Now after pressing the shortcut, all open Terminal windows will change the size to desired size and will be centered.

Study the Devilspie documentation for other possibilities and usage.